# My company, located in a different state, is not withholding local taxes for me

Tags: united-states, income-tax, withholding, withholding-tax

I am a resident of Maryland and I recently began working remotely for a company located in a different state. This company is not deducting local taxes from my paycheck. Will I incur a penalty for not having withheld local taxes? What can I do to resolve this?

This is an excerpt from a communication with payroll:

> [We are] not registered to file any local taxes in Maryland so we will not be deducting anything for them from your pay.

Note: There is no issue with state withholding, just local.

Comment: I'm pretty sure MD local taxes are collected as part of state taxes. (Assuming they're calculating your MD state tax correcty)

Comment: @pboss3010 that's what I expected, but the statement from payroll suggested differently. I have yet to receive a paycheck in which they deduct MD taxes because I began this job recently and they were collecting taxes for the other state on previous paychecks. After receiving my next paycheck I will be able to determine if I am interpreting payroll's statement correctly.

Comment: I do have the impression that nobody but local companies bothers withholding local taxes, simply because there are too many local variations to be worth dealing with. The forms allow it, but...

Comment: You’d think that payroll systems like ADP would do that automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If the employer won't withhold the county/city income taxes you could have additional money withheld. This is done using the [Maryland version of the W-4](https://www.marylandtaxes.gov/statepayroll/Static_Files/Employee_W4/2022_W-4.pdf)

> Step 4C Extra withholding. Enter any additional tax you want withheld
> each pay period.

This will be tricky because you will have to estimate how much will be needed to be withheld to cover the county tax.

The state W-4 will require you to list the county you live in. Check with their payroll processor. If they are using a large one, the payroll processors system should be able to handle this because it will be built into their software.

Comment: Are you sure that is the right form? It says "For Maryland State Government Employees Only" at the top. The form was given my payroll was MW507. MW507 does have an additional withholding question, but my understanding was that was only for state withholding, not local withholding.

Answer (score -1):

Talk to your town's officials.

There may not be any local income taxes. (There aren't for me; the town funds itself primarily on real estate tax.)

If there are, the town will have dealt with this many-to-the-Nth times and will have a standard answer for you. I expect that it's going to be a small enough amount that they don't bother worrying about prepayment/estimated payment/withholding and just send a bill for anything still due, as they do for RE tax and other town fees.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The local income tax is nonzero, but is not very large given how close to the end of the year I started this job. I can see if my county has any information online about how they deal with this.

Comment: MD localities do not administer income taxes. It is handled 100% by the state on the state forms.

Comment: Ok. So they aren't withholding local taxes and there are no local taxes. If so, nothing needs to be done.